# Do monster close and area attacks affect allies by default?

Tags: dnd-4e

Recently I've been seeing several NPC monster entries with blast range attacks that have no stated target included, whereas player abilities often specifically say what they hit. For example:

*Storm Pulse (standard, recharge ) Lightning
Close blast 5; +15 vs Reflex; 2d4+8 lightning damage, and the target is weakened (save ends).*

Is from a npc sheet, while player abilities often say their targets within the blast ("All creatures, all enemies, one creature, etc.")

I'm a bit unsure how to handle this. When an attack doesn't specify what targets within its range to attack like the one above, what should I default to for the target range?

If you want the specific sheet I'm looking at: http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=monster&id=3338 (DDI membership needed)

Comment: I'm poking this one right now. MM1 usually specified enemies or not at all. Checking MM2 and 3 right now to see if they have additional advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monster Manual 2 (p 7) has the answer for you:

> An area attack or a close attack targets each creature within its area of effect, unless otherwise noted.

This gives you your answer. Unless the power specifies "enemies," area and close attacks affect all creatures.